# Date picker Issue in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a textfield in which the user can click which opens the date picker and after selection and clicking done button it paste date in textfield. But, i'm facing an issue that my date picker is not showing when i click the textfield, I'm confused why  is it so my code is i think alright but i don't know why it s not showing date picker, My code is ,

```
datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datepicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;

UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneBtn,space,nil]];
```

The method is this,

```
-(void)ShowSelectedDate{
    NSDateFormatter *fromatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [fromatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
    self.DOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fromatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
}
```

Comment: You did not show us the code where you try to open the date picker.

Comment: its above i'm wrtitig it in viewDidLoad method.@Arasuvel

Comment: @HamzaImran : Check my answer...

Comment: @please show the whole code. It's unable to figure out from this.

Comment: Bro it have a simple textfield in my storyboard and i have take an outlet of it and globally write the UIDatePicker *datepicker; in .h file and i .m file just written the above code. @AdityaSrivastava

Comment: @HamzaImran Where you have added datePicker to view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing only one statement

```
[myTextField setInputView: datepicker];
```

You are not adding picker to view

```
[self.view addSubview:datepicker];
```

To show toolbar you are missing below statement

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Comment: it's showing now but its not showing the barbutoon done above it to select the desired date. @Fahim Parkar

Comment: Its not showing the Done button to select the date, Can u hep me in this?. @Fahim Parkar

Comment: @HamzaImran : Check updated answer.. that will show Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

AS @Fahim said

```
[myTextField setInputView: datepicker];
[self.view addSubview:datepicker];
```

But your toolbar will do problem here. Because you have harcoded it's height and width.
Picker has default height of 216 as far as I know. So, use tollbar like this

```
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216 - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)]; // -44 is for tollbar height
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Bro the date picker is showing ine but the Done button is not showing in Tool bar. @Adtiya Srivastava

Comment: Yaah. See my updated answer @HamzaImran. You have to add it to your view also

Comment: Glat to help you @HamzaImran